# Turn on and let LED stay on if value is over threshold in main while-loop

Tags: led, avr, atmega, c

I'm totally stuck with this rather trivial (?) problem, i've got this pseudo code that i will convert to C (i'm programming a ATmega8 MCU):

```
Include libraries
Threshold = 40 //Celsius

While true
    Temp = Read_temp_from_sensor()

    If Temp > Threshold
         Turn on LED
    Else
         Turn off LED
```

Is there a way to make the LED stay on for the duration of the While-loop but only as long as the temperature read from the sensor is higher than the threshold value?

I'm guessing that i don't want to evaluate the values in the If/Else block at every cycle, am i on the right track here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what you do - you evaluate if/else at every cycle. Your code is basically ok, it just has one flaw - if the temperature is near the threshold your LED will blink rapidly as temperature readings will be above 40 and below 40 a little bit. You might not want that. To avoid this you have to implement *hysteresis* - have some margin temperature has to overcome to either turn LED on or off. Something like this:

```
Threshold = 40 //Celsius
Hysteresis = 1
While true
    Temp = Read_temp_from_sensor()

    If Temp > Threshold + Hysteresis
         Turn on LED
    Else If Temp < Threshold - Hysteresis
         Turn off LED
```

You might want to consider sleeping the microcontroller in between loop cycles, using interrupts form the watchdog to wake it up in equal time intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Your pseudocode (along with the hysteresis miceuz explained in his answer) should work fine. Sometimes, depending on your requirement the hysteresis may not be required in that a flickering LED is good for what you want to do. Its a somewhat unusual requirement, but it does come up from time to time.

I would like to note, however, that doing this in the main loop could be problematic in some use cases. If the loop itself is long or filled with blocking calls (say a serial read function which returns only after a message is received), then this could cause some lagging in the LEDs response. If the response time is important to you, you may want to make sure that the main loop executes within a period less than the desired response time.

Alternate solutions are available. They are possibly too complicated to be of more than academic interest for simple applications, but you never know when you'd need more.

- Run the LED code as a function or so which is executed periodically, again with a period shorter than the desired response time. This 'function' could be triggered from an interrupt, or in much more complicated systems, as a task in a real time operating system.
- If the get temperature function is using the ADC, you could instead configure the ADC as a comparator if you don't care what the actual temperature is (or maybe use a separate channel of the ADC as a comparator, which i *think* the AVR allows), and use the comparator interrupt to trigger the LED. This wouldn't need regular checking and would essentially guarantee very quick response.
- If the threshold is also going to be used for some kind of safety cutoff, or for triggering a fast ADC measurement burst where you're trying to detect something that happens just after (sort of like an oscilloscope trigger), it may be worthwhile to bypass he AVR entirely and use a real comparator. They're cheap,  easy to use, fast, and can be hooked up to one of the AVRs pin change interrupts (called external interrupt on the mega8).